# left join query not executing data

Tags: mysql

I have `userID` - `1` and I have two tables `assign_salon` and `salons`. I want get data from `salons` table. I want get salon `name` and `id`

`assign_salon` where is `userID` and `salonID`

`Salons` where is all salon info. so I know which user is owns/works on this salon.

My query what doesnt give any data. I dont know why. I have data in tables.

QUERY:

```
SELECT 
   s.name,
   s.id 
FROM salons AS s
LEFT JOIN assign_salon AS sa ON s.id = sa.salonID 
WHERE sa.userID = 1
```

Comment: can you please some data example [mre]

Comment: You said `Salons` in your question and have `salons` in your query. Typo?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: Does your table have records?